# Locally(-)injective mapping--hyphenate or not?

Tags: hyphenation

Do I need to to hyphenate:

"It is a locally-injective mapping."

where I use locally injective as a term--a concept:

"This mapping is locally injective."

For example, it is defined in:

[Weber14 "Locally Injective Parametrization with Arbitrary Fixed Boundaries"]

[http://www.eng.biu.ac.il/~weberof/Publications/Selfoverlapping/Locally_Injective_Parametrization_with_Arbitrary_Fixed_Boundaries.pdf](http://www.eng.biu.ac.il/%7Eweberof/Publications/Selfoverlapping/Locally_Injective_Parametrization_with_Arbitrary_Fixed_Boundaries.pdf)

---

Adding some links regarding hyphenating the adverb 'well', which may be relevant:

A Well-Known Problem: Hyphens With “Well” Words
https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2009/07/a-wellknown-problem-well-known.html

Well-Hyphenated Compound Adjectives
https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/favart/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr8O0GT3FD1GuY&page=9p1twFAGORMI.html

---

"The elements of style" by Strunk and White says:

"When two or more words are combined to form a compound adjective, a hyphen
is usually required."

---

The wiki page is quite comprehensive and sounds convincing:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Compound_modifiers

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Please give the definition in context in your question; an excerpt from that link perhaps would be helpful.

Comment: Since *locally* is an adverb, people will assume that it is modifying the following adjective, *injective*. No hyphen is needed.